# How to get value of inputSelectOption in controller lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, aura

I have a lightning component which fetches all the recordtypes of an object. The user kan select the desired recordtype from a picklist. How do I get the selected label or value in my controller. I tried below but this returns an empty label.

Component

```
Select a Record Type<br/>
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="selectid">
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstOfRecordType}" var="rectype">                            
                            <ui:inputSelectOption text="{!rectype}" label="{!rectype}"/>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                <br/><br/>
                 <lightning:button class="slds-button slds-button-#brand" onclick="{!c.createRecord}">Next</lightning:button>
```

Controller

```
createRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.isOpen", true);
    var recordTypeLabel = component.find("selectid").get("v.label");
        alert('recordTypeLabel: '+recordTypeLabel);
```

Comment: you used same value (`{!rectype}`) for both `label` and `text`, so it gives same value, if you use different value for `text` then only we can get by index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot get `label` as its not present in it. But you can get selected value by using:

```
var recordTypeLabel = component.find("selectid").get("v.value");
```

**Note:** you will get `label` when you define label on it. You can say

```
<ui:inputSelect label="Some Label" aura:id="selectid">
```

Then `component.find("selectid").get("v.label")` will return `Some Label`

---

**Important:** It is recommended to use `lightning` base components (like `lightning:select` or `lightning:combobox`) instead of `ui` base components.

Comment: I want to get the label of the selected input. In you rxample I dont get the selected input or am I missing something? I want to get:  label="{!rectype}"

Comment: Value (text) and label are same in select options. So use value. It's same as label